# When I trigger an event, it is fired few times instead one time on input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code, simple one:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="hidden" />
<input type="button" value="ok" />
```

and javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(":text").on("keyup", function(){
        $(":hidden").val($(this).val()).trigger("propertychange");
    });

    $(":hidden").on("propertychange", function(){
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });

    $(":button").on("click", function(){
        alert($(":hidden").val()); 
    });
});
```

When I type something in input type `text` then alert is displayed few times instead of once time.

How to fix it ?

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkvgzc5p/). (I checked with Firefox)

Comment: Use should use ``triggerHandler`` instead of ``trigger``

Comment: Very good, thanks for point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `:hidden` selector is actually matching 8 elements (including `<head>`, `<title>` and `<script>`) instead of only the hidden input, hence the `propertyChange` event is raised for each one.

From jQuery [hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) documentation:

> In some browsers :hidden includes head, title, script, etc...

Try this instead:

```
$("input:hidden").on("input propertychange", function(){
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Also works if use `triggerHandler` instead of `trigger` (see gowri's comment)

Comment: Good point for hidden, I never thought for not visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
$(":text").on("keyup", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(":hidden").val($(this).val()).trigger("propertychange");
   alert($(this).val()); 
});

$(":hidden").on("input propertychange", function(){

});

$(":button").on("click", function(){
    alert($(":hidden").val()); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply any class or ID to hidden, due to using fiddle, it is accessing some other hidden objects also. Try below code.

```
$(function(){
    $(":text").on("keyup", function(){
        $(".md:hidden").val($(this).val()).trigger("propertychange");
    });

    $(".md:hidden").on("input propertychange", function(){
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });

    $(":button").on("click", function(){
        alert($(".md:hidden").val()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Not necessarry to put a class name, is enough to specify the tag name like `input` or `select` or whatever

Comment: Yeap, you can do it that way, but adding class makes life easy.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle check this `[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkvgzc5p/2/)`